# BizTalk receive location process files one by one?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Is there a way in BizTalk to process messages dropped in a folder location (using file adapter) one at a time? I do not want all the messages in the folder get picked all at once.

Comment: I think you mean ordered processing rather that serializable which is the process of converting an object into a stream of bytes to store the object or transmit it to memory, a database, or a file

Comment: Well...why not?  What is you actual business case here?  There may be other ways to address this.

Comment: Basically, I have a web service exposed. I receive the incoming XML and create a request to another request-response service. Now, this request-response service for some limitation cannot process the requests when there are multiple requests hit at it and It gets crashed. Hence, I would want to control the requests being sent to this web service one at a time.

Comment: Then why not set the send port to that web service to ordered delivery?

Answer (score 1):

Not using the native file adapter in BizTalk.

You would have to write a custom file adapter using the sample project in the SDK that can be found under `<BizTalkDirectory>\SDK\Samples\AadaptersDevelopment\FileAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

I can understand why you want this.

In case of a lot of files flush in your intake folder, and if processing the file in pipeline takes extremely long time, it is easy to stuck all the files in pipeline.

In case of you don't want to write a custom adapter, an alternative solution I have used is using Loopback adapter.

What I did before is keep the file receive port as is and make it use passthrough pipeline. Then a loopback adapter will subscribe the message from this file receive port. You can apply your expected pipeline in Loopback ports receive port. and enforce one by one message process by enabling Ordered Delivery